# How can I translate RokSprocket views?

Tags: joomla-3.x, overrides, language

I'm using RokSprocket (from RocketTheme) to create the layout I want on my website, but it's a multilingual site, and I want to translate some of the strings.

I looked for `en-GB.mod_roksprocket.ini` in the `\languages` folder, but it's not there. Then I found it in `\components\com_roksprocket\language\en-GB`, but it only contains one line:

```
READ_MORE="Read More"
```

How can I translate other strings, like the sort options from the "Mosaic" view (<kbd>Default</kbd> <kbd>Title</kbd> <kbd>Date</kbd> <kbd>Random</kbd>)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have to admit the structure for this extension is a little complex, but the file you're looking for is:

```
com_roksprocket/site/layouts/mosaic/language/en-GB/en-GB.roksprocket_layout_mosaic.ini
```

From line 9 to 13, you will see the following:

```
ROKSPROCKET_MOSAIC_ORDERING_DEFAULT="Default"
ROKSPROCKET_MOSAIC_ORDERING_TITLE="Title"
ROKSPROCKET_MOSAIC_ORDERING_DATE="Date"
ROKSPROCKET_MOSAIC_ORDERING_RANDOM="Random"
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you. Any idea why they don't use the normal /languages/ folder?

Comment: I think they split it up as they preferred to keep translations for each view separately, making it easier when searching for the string in the file